# DNS Propagation does not seem to happen

Tags: domain-name-system

I created a new domain at netcup.de to host a Nextcloud. But for some reason the domain (cloud.stammkirkias.de) does not seem to be propagated. Has anyone of you has a tip, why?
As additional information, my brother created a separate DNS-TXT entry for the domain as he said, since it did not work for some reason with a wildcard for the main domain (which is working) stammkirkias.de.

And I am not super experienced when it comes to web hosting, so be kind to me :)
Thank you all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the vendor needs to be engaged.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a screenshot?
I think there is a typo or any misconfig. I directly queried the responsible DNS [root-dns.netcup.net.], but it does not recognize your subdomain, so it is not a matter of propagation

Also note that, the authoritative DNSs are:
root-dns.netcup.net.
third-dns.netcup.net.
second-dns.netcup.net.

Maybe you are adding the record to the wrong DNS?

Comment: Thank you already, but of what exactly do you want a screenshot? Then i will gladly provide one.

Comment: Please make sure that you are creating those records on "netcup" DNS, You can can send me a screenshot of the records you created